# How to merge create.php, remove.php, edit.php

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to write an admin panel and I use 3 different PHP files: `create.php`, `edit.php` and `remove.php`.
Is there any way to merge all of them into one PHP file?

```
<?php 

include 'connection.php';

$id = $_POST['id'];
$soru = $_POST['soru'];
$cevap = $_POST['cevap'];


if (!$_POST['submit'] ) {
    echo "Please fill out the form";
} else {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO sss (soru,cevap,ID) VALUES ('$soru','$cevap','$id') ") or die(mysql_error());

    header('Location:admin.php');


}
?>
```

---

```
<?php 

include 'connection.php';

$id = $_POST['id'];
$soru = $_POST['soru'];
$cevap = $_POST['cevap'];


if (!$_POST['submitSoru'] ) {
    echo "Please fill out the form";
} else {
    mysql_query("UPDATE sss SET soru = '$soru' , cevap = '$cevap' WHERE ID = '$id' ") or die(mysql_error());

    header('Location:admin.php');
?>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to merge them?

Comment: You are open to SQL injections with this code. You should also update your driver to `PDO` or `mysqli`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a better idea. Make an `index.php` file which contains:

```
<?php

    $action = $_GET['action'];
    if ($action == 'create') {
        include('create.php');
    } elseif ($action == 'remove') {
        include('remove.php');
    } elseif ($action == 'edit') {
        include('edit.php');
    } else
        echo "This page does not exist.";

?>
```

So when you access the link for example: `http://example.com/index.php?action=create` this will include `create.php` file in the `index.php` etc..

Comment: all your conditional statements will always be true. Don't assign, compare.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks, edited.